# Custom layout of spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm developing an Android application, I have to implement a custom layout for a spinner item.

I would realize a spinner like this:

[image]

I have a problem to implement the "gold arrow and border".

This is my code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_language"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="10dip"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dip"/>
```

This is my spinner layout:

```
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/custom_black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

How i can realize it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, this will help you..

1) In drawable folder--->add spinner_border.xml for border of spinner.

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
     <corners android:radius="0dp" />
     <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#B4925A" />
```

2)In layout design of spinner use this drop down "arrow_icon" for imageview src

```
     <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

If there any further query,please inform, Thanks...

Comment: I have only 1 problem, the border it's ok, but the dropdown list element no. I want the background of each element black, now i see white background, how i can setup the color ?

Comment: add in spinner   "android:popupBackground="@android:color/black""

Comment: Last question: I have to insert the arrow in my spinner, how i can do this ?
Your code add one image but not in the spinner (look my image)

Answer (score 0):

This is spinner item layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:drawableRight="your_drawable"
    android:drawableEnd="your_drawable"/>
```

Then, you can use it when you're creating spinner adapter, for example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,your_spinner_item_layout, arrayList);
```

ofc drawableRight for pre lollipop devices :)

Comment: I dont understand what i must insert into "your_drawable"

Comment: ohhh sorry, I misunderstood :)

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly. You need to change the layout of the spinner to obtain  a border around the dropdown list like in the image

Comment: hah, my answer was correct :) put in drawableRight/End, it can be arrow or something else :) you can find icons here: https://design.google.com/icons/

Comment: Your answer is wrong, sorry, but actually I have the same spinner the you can see in the image but is all black NOT GOLD, i want it gold

Comment: then change drawable background color to gold and put them i ArrayAdapter constructor :)